# Batch permission insert via Google Drive SDK C# update the last modify date to the Time.NOW

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

Batch permission insert via Google Drive SDK C#.

After uploading the file the last modified date is ok (12.5.2021)

but after assign permission to this file the last modify date is being update to Date.Time.NOW

how i can prevent this to happen. i want to preserve my last modify date .

i am updating the  permissions suing the batch request .

is that something that can affect ?